# Does Sentry APM show detailed application memory usage?

Tags: sentry, apm

We have integrated the Sentry APM to try and find why one particular page in our C#.NET/MSSQL/ASP.NET web application is sometimes slow for one particular customer on a production site. It's low traffic (less than 5 simultaneous users at most) but we have seen the IIS w3wp.exe process bloat to over 20GB of memory use at times. The page does do some complex querying with Entity Framework and the code is quite old. I was hoping the APM would give us some clues to pinpoint where the problem may be but so far all I can see are the queries it generates and the time for each page. I don't see memory use anywhere. I have these questions about Sentry:

1. Is detailed memory use available to see anywhere in the Sentry APM?
2. Should we also implement profiling and inject checkpoints at various places? I was hoping to avoid that as the APM implementation was reasonably painless.
3. In other APM tools we were able to see a whole page's time in one place including client-side time, network transfer time, backend app server time and database server time separately. I can't find a unified view like that in Sentry even though we have integrated both the .NET and the JS Sentry into the project. Is a full breakdown available?

We are on the paid trial and will likely switch to paid because the insights so far have been useful, if not as useful as hoped; I'm trying to decide if we should try another APM again (those sometimes broke our application so we stopped using them, Sentry has so far not  done that, and we tested extensively). Thank you.